# Dominating Sets

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph without any isolated vertices. Let $S$ be a minimal [dominating
set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) for $G$ (in other words, no subset of $S$ is a dominating set for $G$).

i. Prove that $V(G)$ − $S$ is also a dominating set for $G$.

ii. Prove that $V(G)$ − $S$ is not necessarily minimal.

I'm really stumped with these questions, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

i. A set $S$ is *dominating* if for every vertex $v \in V$, either $v \in S$ or $v$ is a neighbour of a vertex in $S$. Therefore to prove that $V \setminus S$ is dominating, you must prove that every vertex not in $V \setminus S$ is a neighbour of a vertex in $V \setminus S$. For this kind of question it can really help to draw a diagram! In particular, this diagram would have two groups of vertices: $V$ and $V \setminus S$, with some edges between them.

ii. Try constructing a counterexample on 3 vertices.

Comment: Also: it's not strictly necessary here, but if it helps, you could prove (i) by contradiction. In other words, suppose that $V \setminus S$ is *not* a dominating set. Going by the definition of 'dominating', what would that imply? Then show that this contradicts the assumption that $V$ is dominating.